# Choice of iterative solver for a sparse asymmetric matrix with symmetric structure

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, symmetry

I have a sparse $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with a pretty interesting structure. It has a block structure with a symmetric structure but asymmetric blocks. Expressed mathematically the block $A_{jk} = A_{kj}$ but $A_{jk} \neq A_{jk}^T$, so my matrix is not actually symmetric. Are there any algorithms that can take advantage of this kind of system?

Comment: There would a possibility of an advantage if various block submatrices commute.

Answer (score 1):

The PARDISO solver from oneMKL supports structurally symmetric matrices. Quoting from the [Intel oneMKL library](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/onemkl-pardiso-parallel-direct-sparse-solver-iface.html#GUID-071D5322-DBE3-44FF-8F53-0EF5509543CB) documentation:

> **Structurally Symmetric Matrices**
>
> The solver first computes a symmetric fill-in reducing permutation P followed by the parallel numerical factorization of $PAP^T = QLU^T$. The solver uses partial pivoting in the supernodes and an approximation of $X$ is found by forward and backward substitution and optional iterative refinement.

The library also supports block-sparse storage formats.

I'd also have a look at the [PANUA - PARDISO](https://panua.ch/pardiso/), which has improved threading and GPU capabilities. A license can be obtained free of charge for academic users.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your mathematical description seems wrong: $A_{jk} = A_{kj}, \forall\ k,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ implies that the matrix is symmetric. So it is not entirely clear what you mean. Also, $A^T_{jk}$ is exactly defined via $A^T_{jk} = A_{kj}$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)). This would somehow be in conflict to your equations.

As to the actual question: While I am not sure what your structure actually is - I am also not aware of any method that might exploit a structure that resembles yours. For a nice overview on iterative methods I'd recommend the [templates book](https://www.netlib.org/templates/templates.pdf). But the most "structure exploitation" there is with regard to symmetry. I hope this helps some..

Comment: Is it possible that Flusslauf means that the locations of the non-zeros is symmetric but their values are different? There was some work done in the late '90s/early 2000s to show that ILU preconditioners which allowed fill in the locations that were structurally non-zero did better than the ILU preconditioners with levels of fill or thresholds, but I don't have that reference handy. These are very challenging to parallelize for distributed memory machines with MPI.

Comment: Ajk refers the the blocks not the individual entries which is why I talk about the transpose of the block Ajk. The transpose of an individual element would not make sense.

Comment: @EMP, usually $A_{jk}$ means the $j,k^{\rm th}$ element of matrix $A$ not the block, so some people are confused by your question. There's really no standard notation that I'm aware of to denote a block vs. an element.

Comment: Agreed that there's not typically a good way to delineate block versus element, I have seen the use of indices to refer to blocks rather than elements in some papers. But the lack of clarity is why I had specified the problem beforehand discussing the block structure and also I think the use of the transpose notation makes it pretty clear I'm discussing the blocks.